# How to capture a certain number of characters after a substring?

Tags: python, string, substring

I'm very new to coding and need help on one last question of an assignment that has me stumped. I can't use regular expressions for this assignment, either.

I've got this string, and I've made it so I split the string after `'cat'` occurs.

```
astr = 'accaggcatgattgcccgattccatgcggtcag'
x = astr.split('cat',1)[-1]
print(x)
gattgcccgattccatgcggtcag
y = astr.split('cat',2)[-1]
print(y)
gcggtcag
```

However, what can I do if I only want the three letters after each `'cat'` in the string? For example, I'd want to get `'gat'` and `'gcg'`.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also get all of them in one go:

```
[x[:3] for x in astr.split('cat')[1:]]
```

Output:

```
['gat', 'gcg']
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was after. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Use slicing, like `[:3]`:

```
astr = 'accaggcatgattgcccgattccatgcggtcag'
x = astr.split('cat',1)[-1][:3]
print(x)
y = astr.split('cat',2)[-1][:3]
print(y)
```

Output:

```
gat
gcg
```

Also, another idea could be:

```
print(list(map(lambda x: x[:3],astr.split('cat')[1:])))
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the `[-1]`? I am trying to solve problems to learn python (VBA mod here) and I tried to use the `find` method to solve this but would like to understand your solution

Comment: @urdearboy The purpose of it is to get the last element, so `[-2]` is second last, and `[-3]` is third last and so on.. here we're doing to a list, so last element of the list, also see [this hot question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Comment: Oh boy. I can tell that VBA being my first language is going to make this language hard to learn. I keep going for end results how I would in VBA and then I try to compare what I did to what others post and the methods are so different. *bless stack overflow for endless practice problems with endless answer lists*